# Quarterly mean by group

Tags: pandas

I have a DataFrame with monthly observations (var1, var2) for a group (Area)

```
  date     var1     var2    Area

 2008-03-01 2       22      OH
 2008-02-01 3       33      OH
 2008-01-01 4       44      OH
 ... etc
 2008-03-01 111    1111     AK
 2008-02-01 222    2222     AK
 2008-01-01 333    3333     AK
```

I wish to 'downsample' these variables to quarterly data by taking the 3-month mean. I.e. The first quarterly observation (var1) for 'OH' should be (1+3+4)/3.

How do I do this in pandas? Thank you

EDIT: Here is what I intended the output to be:

```
      dateQtr      var1     var2    Area

     2008-Q1        3        33       OH
     2007-Q4       ...        ...     OH    
     ... etc
     2008-Q1       222      2222     AK
```

Comment: Is this what you want?  `df.groupby('Area')[['var1','var2']].resample('q')
`  It is basically the same as one of @EdChum's suggestions but it will preserve the date.

Comment: @JohnE yes what you suggested gives the OP what they want, I've updated my answer, I should've realised that doing the `resample` after grouping should work

Comment: Cool, good edits to question and answer.  ;-)

Comment: Just a tiny followup question: when we have problems like this one that can be solved by some kind of `groupby` "magic": how do you guys proceed to figure out the proper procedure? I am always amazed by the one-liner answer to most of these problems. I would never have been able to come up with `df.groupby('Area')[['var1','var2']].resample('q').reset_index()` by myself... Thanks for any pointers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the index to 'date' then you can [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html#pandas.DataFrame.resample) quarterly:

```
In [114]:    
df.resample('q')

Out[114]:
             var1    var2
date                     
2008-03-31  112.5  1127.5
```

So on your existing df:

```
In [116]:    
df.set_index('date').resample('q', how='mean')

Out[116]:
             var1    var2
date                     
2008-03-31  112.5  1127.5
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to @JohnE for pointing this out:

```
In [134]:    
df.groupby('Area')[['var1','var2']].resample('q').reset_index()

Out[134]:
  Area       date  var1  var2
0   AK 2008-03-31   222  2222
1   OH 2008-03-31     3    33
```

Comment: Thank you, I am getting `DataError: No numeric types to aggregate` when I do this on my DataFrame though. Any idea?

Comment: It means your data are strings not numeric, try this first `df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)`

Comment: Thank you, that worked, but how do I retain the `Area` column?

Comment: So maybe you really want `df.groupby([df.index.quarter, 'Area']).mean()` and then call `reset_index()` on the groupby object

Comment: Thanks, but then I lost the date/quarter-info, this wasn't easy :P

Comment: Yeah this gets tricky here you'd have to merge/add back the additional info if you want to retain it

Comment: You could do `df.groupby([df.index.quarter, 'Area']).mean().reset_index()` but the new level columns may confuse you

Comment: Yeah this was much harder than I thought, I think I'll try and get this done in Excel before I import into Python.

Comment: No, not excel!!!  ;-)  It is really easy to do in pandas, but you haven't been real clear about exactly what you want.  Often the best thing to do is show your desired output to avoid confusion.

Comment: @JohnE : Thank you for the suggestion, I have edited my post now, and hope it is clearer now.